# Issue with Liferay UI tab Navigation

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I am using `<liferay-ui:tabs>` for displaying jsp pages as tabs. I am able to see my pages as tabs but If I navigate to one of my pages in the tab and on click of the button then it is navigating to some other page, that it showing in a separate page instead of showing under that tab. I need to click of button events the control should be still under the tabs. my Code is as follows,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><%@include file="/html/users/init.jsp"%>
<portlet: defineObjects />
<portlet:renderURL var="navigateTabURL"/>
<% String navigateTab = ParamUtil.getString(request, "tabs1","Current"); %>
<liferay-ui:tabs names="Current, Available" url="<%=navigateTabURL.toString()%>" >
    <c:if test='<%= navigateTab.equalsIgnoreCase("Current")%>' >
        <jsp:include page="current_members.jsp" flush="true" />
    </c:if>
    <c:if test='<%= navigateTab.equalsIgnoreCase("Available")%>' >
        <jsp:include page="available_members.jsp" flush="true" />
    </c:if>
</liferay-ui:tabs>
```

The pages "Current" and "Available" are showing correctly, But If I click any button in my Current page it is navigating to some other jsp I need that jsp also under that tabs only not showing as a separate page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><%@include file="/html/users/init.jsp"%>
<portlet: defineObjects />
<%
    List<User> userList = (List) request.getAttribute("UserGroupList");        
    //out.println(userList.size());
%>
<%! 
    List<User> users = null;
    int totalNoOfUsers=0;
    String value = null;
%>
<%
    //totalNoOfUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();
    totalNoOfUsers = userList.size();
    users = userList;
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found" rowChecker="<%= new RowChecker(renderResponse) %>" >
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%= ListUtil.subList(users,searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd()) %>"
    total="<%= totalNoOfUsers %>">
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.liferay.portal.model.User" keyProperty="userId"        modelVar="user">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter name="userIds" value="<%= user.getUserId()%>">
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row-parameter>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="UserName" value="
            <%= user.getScreenName()%>" />
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="First Name" value="<%= user.getFirstName() %>">
            </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Last Name" value="<%= user.getLastName() %>">
            </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp align="right" path="/html/users/custom_user_actions.jsp" />
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
    </liferay-ui:search-container>
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found" />

<portlet:actionURL name="viewEntry" var="viewEntryURL"></portlet:actionURL>
<aui:form action="<%= viewEntryURL %>" name="<portlet:namespace />fms">
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Cancel"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

How do I navigate the tabs as dynamic requests. Any suggestions please!!

Comment: What do you want to achieve on click on Cancel?

Comment: On click of Cancel button I am navigating to some other jsp page. If I navigate to that page I am not be able to see the UI tabs (current and available). I don't need this. I need to navigate that new jsp page under that tab only. Like need to replace the tab content with new request page parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain a tab selection, "value" attribute of  should be mentioned with name of tab to select.
If "value" attribute not specified then first tab will be considered as active.

For example, please refer following file in liferay portal sources.

```
portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/dockbar/add_panel.jsp
```

Also, below post in liferay forum should help.

http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4809190